# Android geofencing minimum requirements?

Tags: android, geofencing

Which android version is required for android new **Geofencing** feature ? Not able to get particular information on **[Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.html)**..

Comment: Same that for any feature of Google Play Services... 8 (like any services feature, I guess)

Comment: guys, will this work indoors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Waza_Be commented it requires API8 and will work on devices with at least Froyo.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Google Geofence API you need Google Play services. Devices older than Android 2.2 or devices without the Google Play Store app are not supported.